# Why is local Storage saving undefined?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am fairly new to JavaScript and trying to get the text from the entry field added to local storage when the box is clicked out of. I have managed to get it to save the key and the field however the data is returned as undefined. please can some tell me why.

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My Erehwon Diary ZX141632</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Stephen Rice" />
    <!-- Set viewport to ensure this page scales correctly on mobile devices -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tma03.css" />
    <!-- Set demo data -->
    <script src="tma03-demo.js"></script>
    <!-- Start TMA03 application -->
    <script src="tma03.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My Erehwon Diary ZX141632</h1>
    <main>
      <section id="text" class="button">
        <button type="button">Add entry</button>
      </section>
      <section id="image" class="button">
        <button type="button">Add photo</button>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" />
      </section>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript code

```
function addTextEntry(key, text, isNewEntry) {
    var textareaElement = document.createElement("textarea");
    textareaElement.rows = 5;
    textareaElement.placeholder = "(new entry)";

    textareaElement.value = text;

    addSection(key, textareaElement);

    if (isNewEntry) {
        textareaElement.focus();
    }

    function saveEntry() {
        var textArea = document.getElementById("text").value;
        var item = makeItem("text", Text);
        localStorage.setItem(key, item);
    }

    textareaElement.addEventListener('change', saveEntry);

}
```

Comment: Wnat's `makeItem`? What's `Text`? Why are you getting the value of a `<section>`?

Comment: Where did you define `Text` It's unclear why you thought it would be anything other than undefined. You should explain what kind of debugging you have done. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking a question

Comment: There's a bunch of stuff that's `undefined`, as far as I can see. You never even call the function. How about a better Example, with at least comments where things aren't defined.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `Text` is indeed undefined, what you can do is:

```
var textArea = document.getElementById("text").value;
 var item = makeItem("text", textArea);
```